# Sub-millisecond latency for Cloud Bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

Under what conditions can Cloud Bigtable achieve sub-millisecond latency?

I had heard that sub-millisecond latency was possible, so to test it, I created an extremely simple Bigtable instance, with the default configuration and a table containing only a single cell. In the same region as the BigTable (Iowa), I ran a simple test:

```py
table = client.instance(instance_name).table(table_name)
start = datetime.datetime.now()
print(table.read_row('1').to_dict())
print(datetime.datetime.now() - start)
```

The latency was 5ms+ and was sometimes 25ms when I ran this after waiting for a bit. Why is it so bad? I was strongly under the impression that it was possible to see <1ms latency, at most 2-3ms. It's the default configuration: SSD storage.

Comment: Bigtable offers "single-digit millisecond latency at the 99th percentile". I'm not sure where you saw something about sub-millisecond latency, but that isn't something Bigtable has any SLOs about.

Comment: Also, you mentioned waiting a bit and seeing more latency – this could be caused by the cold start time needed for the client to connect.

Comment: Ok, opening new question for bigtable about non-sub-millisecond.

Answer (score -1):

As Cloud Bigtable performance is highly dependent on workload, schema design, and dataset characteristics. There are several factors that can cause Bigtable to perform more slowly than the estimates as shown in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance#typical-workloads). It is  recommended to take a look at the causes of [slower performance](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance#slower-perf) to make sure you avoid them.

Also you need to take care that, Poorly designed schema can lead to a poorly performing system. Hence, I recommend you to check out the [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design#best-practices) that apply to most use cases.

Also recommended you to test performance with Bigtable by following these [Guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance#run_your_typical_workloads_against) and [Document](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance#testing) so you can figure out the best resource allocation for your applications.

For latency-sensitive applications it is recommended to keep the storage utilization per node below 60%. Also you need to check with the network latency as well.

Also check with this [Troubleshooting Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance#troubleshooting) which might be helpful.

Comment: This is just the generic advise in the docs. I specifically said that I made the problem simple by creating a table with **a single cell** and the default configuration.

Comment: The latency to be less than 1 ms is really seems not feasible and the 4-5ms range is much more normal when using Bigtable. As suggested, it is recommended to test and run a workload against your [Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance#run_your_typical_workloads_against) to better understand the latency responses.

Comment: Also as @Billy Jacobson, suggested in the comment for `waiting a bit and seeing more latency` this might be due to the cold start time, which is also stated in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance#run_your_typical_workloads_against:~:text=For%20this%20reason%2C%20if%20you%20start%20sending%20requests%20after%20a%20period%20of%20no%20usage%2C%20you%20might%20observe%20high%20latency%20while%20Bigtable%20reestablishes%20connections).

Comment: If you are still facing high latency, feel free to contact [Google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) so that project level investigation can be done.

Comment: As I said many times, this is **single cell** and it is getting 25ms latency with the default configuration. Do not use chatGPT for answers

Comment: I haven’t used any chatgpt answers. Based on some internal debugging, documentation and my knowledge I posted an answer. If you are still facing an issue please feel free to contact [Google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) where the project level debugging will be done.

Comment: It is a basic question: if the google docs advertise sub-1ms latency, and you suggest 4-5ms, then why is the minimal configuaring giving 20ms+? How do you achieve 1 or 5ms latency?