# Single-digit millisecond latency for bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

How can I be reasonably sure that Google Cloud Bigtable will perform with at worst **single-digit** millisecond latency?

The docs state that Bigtable has "single-digit millisecond latency at the 99th percentile"; however, I created an extremely simple Bigtable instance, with the default configuration and a table containing only a single cell. In the same region as the BigTable (Iowa), I ran a simple test:

```py
table = client.instance(instance_name).table(table_name)
start = datetime.datetime.now()
print(table.read_row('1').to_dict())
print(datetime.datetime.now() - start)
```

The latency was 5ms+ and was sometimes 25ms when I ran this after waiting for a bit. What am I doing wrong? Clearly something is different if I'm getting very different results than the docs.

Comment: How are you measuring latency? There are two primary latencies: a) Bigtable query response time; b) network latencies. Network latency is variable and is not included in Google's single-digit latency objectives.

Comment: This question is basically a duplicate of your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76370526/8016720) with minor differences. My advice is to delete this question and update your other question.